# How to publish angular 2 app with Angular 2 CLI +Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I used the following command in my console:

```
ng build --prod
```

and my dist folder has been generated with the following files:

[image]

I've uploaded them to my web host and got the following error:

```
polyfills.c27b87b….bundle.js:1 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'item' since it isn't a known property of 'simple-notification'.
1. If 'simple-notification' is an Angular component and it has 'item' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'simple-notification' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("<simple-notification
                *ngFor="let a of notifications; let i = index"
                [ERROR ->][item]="a"
                [timeOut]="timeOut"
                [clickToClose]="clickToClose"
```

with many different errors of simple-notifications package I'm using in my app.

What do I have to upload in addition to my generated dist folder in order to publish my app?

Comment: Looks like a runtime error that has to do with your SimpleNotification component. Do you have an @Input called item? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child

Comment: Is the command ng serve --prod works ?

Comment: @itamar Hmm.. I don't

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux There are some warnings.. the command works, but I don't think it has to do anything with the errror I see

Comment: Can you access the application through localhost:4200

Comment: Yes @NicolasHenneaux

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with template parsing. You can avoid minify Html.

Template parse is not working properly as it should and angular team has provided a work around on their docs for right now but hope fully it should be fix soon in webpack.config file add this

```
htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },
```

Or

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: `html?-minimize`
}
```

[workaround from angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#production-configuration)
[Also see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39018632/5409081)

Comment: Found the `webpack.config.ts` file in my `node_modules\angular-cli\addon\ng2\models`, did you mean that file or there is any other file that I need to update?